# Show Menu from one WordPress install in another WordPress install

Tags: menus, directory

I did some searching but, not finding exactly what I need.

I'm redesigning a website that has a main WordPress install and a WordPress install in a subdirectory. My client calls it a nightmare. I'm moving pages to the main WP install but, leaving her vlog in the subdirectory.

I need to show the main menu from the main WP install on the pages of that WP install in the subdirectory. Right now, it looks like two different websites. We need it to look like one website.

There was a post from over 5 years ago that suggested an iframe with an include. I don't really want to go that route. Especially if there are more recent solutions.

Thanks,
Eunice

Comment: Why even keep this structure? Just include the subdirectory install into the main one?

Comment: Do you mean that you want it to look the same or do you mean that you want it to automatically updated the menu in the sub-directory when the main site changes?  If it looks different, then copy the header.php and the relevant style.css code over to the subsite theme's header.  (Make a backup first).
If you just need the navigation to match and to link to the main site, then just do custom links in the Dashboard Menus configuration.

Comment: @kero Mainly because there's like a LOT of video blogs on that install and she doesn't want them interfered with. If you know a way to do that without possibly losing or messing up what's there. Please let me know.

Comment: @TonyDjukic Automatically update the menu in the sub-directory when the site changes. AND I need the navigation to match. The sites should be connected and seamless. Yeah, I thought of custom links but, I wanted to see if there was yet another way to do this.

Comment: Yes, I would rather move the videos it but, there's a lot of other work to do on the main site plus I'm updating with current events as I'm redesigning. The other designer created a mess that I'm trying to pull together. I figured the easiest route would be to redesign the sub-directory install, move what I can and leave what would take a great deal of work to move.

Comment: I can see the benefit to automating things but how often does a menu change?  I just wonder if it'll be worth the effort.  I guess what you'd need to then is reference the main site's database through a custom plugin and write your own output routine - that way you're always loading the most up to date version of the menu.  Alternatively you could write a plugin that transfers over the navigation from one DB to the other.  None of that strikes me as a simple undertaking though.  This'll probably need to be a plugin and you'll need to provide DB access/credentials to the plugin.

Comment: @TonyDjukic Thanks for the suggestions and ideas. I appreciate you taking the time to give me options. As I see it now, I'm guessing the first option of custom links is probably my best bet right now. LOL I'm guessing the menu won't change that often. Not sure, I see lots of pages created but, when I first started on this site there was one option on the menu 'Contact' that went nowhere. WP and all of the plugins hadn't been updated in I don't know how long. LOL 

Again, thanks for pitching options. I'll at least know other options should things change.